# Facing licensing issue in already published paid app

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am facing the problem in licensing of my old published paid apps. Basically i have paid app which is published by version code 1. I implemented the license code on it, it working fine to me. Licensing server giving the response or allow that you can use it. But once i changed version code from 1 to 2 in manifest file, then licensing service not allow to use the app.Server giving the response dont allow. I not understanderd, y it has relation with version code? i can't publish the update version.???

Moreover, i am already login to my publisher account, i have setting of LICENSED in edit profile section.

Comment: did you try to publish a new version of your application or did you do "update/upgrade" by going to the page of your application in your dev account?

Comment: Basically i tried to publish my licenced app which is of version 1. but market have rules , you cant upload the same version app again.Because in market, i already have my app (version 1) live but it is not licensed.So i make my app licensed. License lib working fine for version 1 but when i change it to version 2 in manifest file , its licensing failed. So in short, version 1 licensing is useless 4 me bec i can't upload it or version 2 can be upload but its unlicenced... i want version 2 also to be license . Y licensing server not accepting upgrade license version app:(

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly...

From the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html):

> Once an application is uploaded and
>   becomes known to the licensing server,
>   developers and testers can continue
>   modify the application in their local
>   development environment, without
>   having to upload new versions. You
>   only need to upload a new version if
>   the local application increments the
>   versionCode attribute in the manifest
>   file.

So basically upload (but don't publish) your licensed v2, then test v2 in the emulator - it should accept the licensing now.  (You may have to "save" on the app page, but I'm not sure)  If everything is good, click "Publish" to make it live.

Comment: By the way I double-checked this last night and it worked for me.  I didn't have to "Save" the page either, just upload, and it can be tested.

Comment: Hi wirbly, i have uploaded my new licensed version 2 of my application on market. And testing on my emulator but its still not allowing. My version 2 is still not published? Help me plzz...

Comment: I forgot to ask - are you using an AVD with Google APIs?  And are you signed in to your developer account on that AVD?  Both are required.  (Note that you can also sign into the AVD using another account, then add that address as a test account on the market profile page)

Comment: HI WIRBLY. thx 4 the reply. i am testing in AVD of froyo 2.2 (Google API) and login with my market account in google account. The question is that when i changed the version from 1 to 2, goole licensing server not allowing me to use app where when i again change it to 2 from 1, its allowin me to use app. What mistake i am doing ? Please help me....

Comment: I have to admit I'm at a loss.  For me, as long as I set the test mode to "LICENSED" on my profile page, and uploaded (but not published) the app, it worked perfectly during testing.  (sorry about the delayed response - I wish StackOverflow had some kind of notification system)